# Weird behaviour with MFC Modal Dialogs

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, modal-dialog

I just noticed all Modal dialog in my program have a weird behaviour,

The code will stop ad the dlg.DoModal() Call, but the window below it will still be active and accept inputs.
This happen to all my CDialog derived window (It's actually CBCGPDialog) and system messagebox, file dialog etc.

The only conclusion i got is that there must be some message pump that process window messages, even if it should not.

Did this happen to anyone else? And any idea of how to resolve it?

By accepting input i mean they are still responsive.

For example if i have a Add button witch open a Modal dialog after the Dialog is shown i still can click the same button to show another one.

EDIT.

I found the error.

There was some error in the bitmask passed on LoadFrame (for the mainframe).

I don't know witch bit, but one of those will disable some meccanism to make Dialog window work

Comment: There is a message pump otherwise your dialog could not process messages. It will simply dispatch as normal so your owner window procedure will still get called. It's standard behaviour. The owner window should be disabled though, so "accepting" input does sound strange. Can you clarify what you mean here? Is the owner window the one that calls dlg.DoModal()? Is the owner window set correctly when you create your dialog?

Comment: I didnt specified any owner window but yes is the MainWindow the one who call the dialog. It is btw a MDI app.

Comment: Rather than edit your question to say you have found the error you can post an answer to your own question. I'd be interested in seeing the solution.

Comment: Would love to hear your results too. I run into a similar problem but the other way round. Closing a modal moved the modal state to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

`CDialog::DoModal` does a couple of things. First it disables the parent window of the dialog so it will no longer respond to events, then it does the same to the main window obtained via `AfxGetMainWnd()`. It runs its own message pump with `RunModalLoop()`.